# What is the maximum number of sessions allowed on ADB? Is it possible to change it?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

In the documentation for Autonomus Database, parameters that can be modified are listed here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-restrictions-database-initialization-parameters.html#GUID-7CF648C1-0822-4602-8ED1-6F5719D6779E

However, I cannot find a list for parameters which cannot be modified. For example what is the limit of number of sessions allowed on an ADB instance? Is it dependent on number of OCPUs or does it increase with autoscaling?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The number of sessions is 300 per OCPU. It is the base OCPU number that counts. Enabling autoscaling does not increase the number of sessions.

The following query from v$parameter will list the names and default values for each parameter:

```
select name, value from v$parameter order by name;
```

For sessions, you can find more details here:

[Predefined Database Service Names for Autonomous Transaction Processing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpgs/autonomous-connect-database-service-names.html#GUID-9747539B-FD46-44F1-8FF8-F5AC650F15BE)

Answer (score 0):

300 sessions per OCPU.

One can scale upto maximum of 128 OCPUs in an ADB instance as on today.